# Primefaces Mobile - selectOneMenu filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

Is possible to filter selectOneMenu in Primefaces **mobile**?

I need something like [this example (Advanced) in primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml)

[]'s

Comment: Did you TRY to use the normal one on a mobile phone? It just works for me... Most normal versions have mobile functionality in them. So I stopped using the mobile ones (besides the page components, menu bar)

Comment: I'm using the same JSF Managed Bean for both xhtml pages (normal and mobile). The code for p:selectOneMenu is exactly the same in both pages. And the selectOneMenu filter works in the normal page and doesn't works in the mobile page @Kukeltje

Comment: Works for me with the PF showcase on my HTC-M8 although that is not a specific mobile page. Maybe that is the difference, but then you should create a [mcve]